# Select coordinates like google maps in osmdroid?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

Is there a way to select(update) coordinates of a marker like google maps, only by moving the map and not the marker?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with osmdroid, but its api looks similar to the Google Maps api. Check to see if there is something similar to `setOnCameraMoveStartedListener` or `setOnCameraMoveListener`

Answer (score 0):

Solved by implementing mapView.setMapListener() and getting the coordinates of the ScrollEvent.